# Confused about installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I read the install tutorial and am confused as to how to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. In the guide it said it can be done but the window in the guide (Use the checkboxes to choose whether you'd like to Install Ubuntu alongside another operating system) but it doesn't show which choice to choose for the install alongside Windows.

Comment: Do you *need* to install it alongside? Have you tried the Live environment without installing? Have you considered installing in a free, Windows-hosted Virtual Machine?  If you *want* to dual, boot, we can certainly help but there are other, easier options too.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot the live USB
2. Connect to the internet (wifi or Ethernet)
3. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

   ```
   sudo apt install gparted
   sudo gparted
   ```
4. Resize the size of your Windows partition, ('free space after' is the size of your Ubuntu install (I suggest making the Ubuntu look around the same size or 1/4 of the total size))
5. Wait!!! This will take a very long time depending on your computers storage size
6. Launch the installer, select <kbd>Something else</kbd> when you get to the screen you described
7. Select the free space, click <kbd>add</kbd>, select `ext4` and `/`
8. Click <kbd>Continue</kbd> the install will continue
9. When you boot, grub will give you a choice between <kbd>Windows</kbd> and <kbd>Ubuntu</kbd>

Comment: Please have a look at my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1005663/revisions) as it's better now and worthy of an upvote...  **:-)**